# Fetch API data while scrolling REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I'm new in react trying building Anime WEB APP.
The problem is when I'm trying to fetch new data and store the new data with the prev data in my state,
but before it store it `setIsLoading` becomes true and all apps crash with problem:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'canonicalTitle' of undefined

This is my code:

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import Card from './cards'


function Movies(){

const [data , setData] = useState([])
const [isLoading , setIsLoading] = useState(true)
const [value , SetValue] = useState('')
const [isBottom, setIsBottom] = useState(false);
const [page , setPage] = useState(0)

const style={
    fontSize: "2rem", 
    textAlign: "center" ,
    borderRadius:"25px",
    padding : "0% 20%" ,
    marginLeft:"19%"
}


const LISTED_API= `https://kitsu.io/api/edge/anime?page[limit]=20&page[offset]=${page}`
const SEARCH_API = `https://kitsu.io/api/edge/anime?filter[text]=$`




useEffect(()=>{
        readData(LISTED_API)    
},[page])


//FEATCHING API DATA , SET DATA , Set Loading //
const readData = (API)=> {
    setIsLoading(true)
    fetch(API)
     .then((res)=>res.json())
     .then((data)=>{
         setData(data.data)
        })
     .then(setIsLoading(false))
 }

//search handel//
function handelChange(e){
    const searchValue = e.target.value
        SetValue( searchValue)
        readData(SEARCH_API+searchValue)

        if (!searchValue){
            readData(LISTED_API)
        }

}
//Listen to Scroll //
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  }, []);


//Set True if reach Buttom//
function handleScroll(){
        if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
            setIsBottom(true)
         }else{
             setIsBottom(false)
         }
}




useEffect(() => {
    if (isBottom) { 
        setPage((prev)=>prev + 20)
        setData((prev)=>{
            return [...prev ,[data]]
        })
    }
  }, [isBottom]);


    

return(<div>

<header>

   <input style={style} type="text" name="name" placeholder="Search..." onChange={(e)=>{handelChange(e)}} />
   
   <h1>{value}</h1>

</header>

<div className="grid-container">

{isLoading ? 'Loading...' : data.map(e=>
      <Card 
      key={e.id}
     id={e.id}
    name={e.attributes.canonicalTitle}
    img={e.attributes.posterImage.small}
    description={e.attributes.description}/>     
       
    )}

</div>


</div>)
}
    export default Movies
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setData` inside the `if (isBottom)` part of your last `useEffect` is appending an array to the `data` state, causing the `data.map` later on to have en element where `e.attributes` is undefined, causing your error message.

You should remove the `setData((prev)=>{return [...prev ,[data]]})` bit from there, and instead call `readData`. Then in your `readData` method you can put `setData(prev => [...prev, ...data.data])`, meaning that `setData` only gets called once, and is called correctly.